# Can I use Solve to solve for an expression (instead of a variable)?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have an equation:$$ds^2=-(C_1+A\space t)^2 dt^2+C_2^2 dr^2$$How would I re-arrange this formula to get an expression of $\frac{dr}{dt}$? $C_1$, $C_2$ and $A$ are constants.  I know the answer is:$$\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{ds+(C_1+A\space t)dt}{C_2 dt}$$This would allow me to make a substitution of $D[r,t]=\frac{dr}{dt}$ and solve the problem as an ODE, but I'm stuck trying to get the LHS of the equation in this form.  Ideally, I'd like to do this:

```
Solve[ds^2=-(C_1+A*t)^2 dt^2+C_2^2 dr^2,dr/dt]
```

Are there any tricks?

Comment: It's just a jargon from relativistic theory. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function) for what Hadamard said about such differentials: Enfin, que signifie ou que représente l'égalité $d^2z = r\,dx^2 + 2s\,dx\,dy + t\,dy^2\,?$, A mon avis, rien du tout. Without a precise formulation, who would do something about it?

Comment: @yarchik Are you sure you answered the right question? The question is really about some sort of upgraded `Solve` function, not relativity or differentials.

Comment: You could try `Reduce[{q == dr/dt, ds^2 == -(C[1] + A*t)^2 dt^2 + C[2]^2 dr^2}, {q}, {dr, dt}]`. However it does not directly reproduce your result. Are you sure of it? Could ds be zero?

Comment: @TannerLegvold If one naively solves for $dr$ and divides the result by $dt$ one gets quite different answer. Only by assuming that $dr$, $dt$ and $ds$ are infinitesimally small, one can derive the final equation.

Comment: @MarcoB - It looked promising, but **Reduce** appears to be finicky.  It works with the constants, but if I replace the constants with constant expressions, it fails to find a solution.  If I substitution my actual values for $C_1$ and $C_2$ out of the expression, use **Reduce** and then sub them back in, I've got something uglier than what I currently have.  Thanks for the effort though, that was the general idea of what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let us mention two syntax errors in your code.

First, the underscore has a special meaning in Mma. Therefore, notations like `C_1` are illegal. Use `C1` instead.

Second, the use of `Solve` requires that the `Equal`, rather than `Set` stays in the expression you want to be interpreted as an equation. Therefore, use `==` instead of `=`.

After fixing this, the answer to your question is not very difficult. I will do it starting with your original idea.

Here is your equation and its solution:

```
sol = Solve[ds^2 == -(C1 + A*t)^2 dt^2 + C2^2 dr^2, dr][[2, 1]]


(*  dr -> Sqrt[ds^2 + C1^2 dt^2 + 2 A C1 dt^2 t + A^2 dt^2 t^2]/C2 *)
```

By default, Mma returns the solution in the form of a rule. Let us transform it into an equation:

```
eq1 = Equal @@ sol

(*  dr == Sqrt[ds^2 + C1^2 dt^2 + 2 A C1 dt^2 t + A^2 dt^2 t^2]/C2  *)
```

Let us now divide the both parts of this equation by `dt`:

```
eq2 = Assuming[{dt != 0}, DivideSides[eq1, dt]]

(*  dr/dt == Sqrt[ds^2 + C1^2 dt^2 + 2 A C1 dt^2 t + A^2 dt^2 t^2]/(C2 dt)  *)
```

Now, let us bring `dt` under the square root:

```
eq3 = expr1 /. Sqrt[a_]/dt :> Sqrt[a/dt^2]

(*  dr/dt == Sqrt[(
 ds^2 + C1^2 dt^2 + 2 A C1 dt^2 t + A^2 dt^2 t^2)/dt^2]/C2  *)
```

and let us, further, expand the expression under the radical:

```
MapAt[Expand, expr2, {2, 2, 1}]

(*  dr/dt == Sqrt[C1^2 + ds^2/dt^2 + 2 A C1 t + A^2 t^2]/C2   *)
```

[image]

Done. Have fun!